# ¿Como remplazar los espacios en String por guiones bajos?

Tags: php, string

```
$cadena = "Esta es la cadena que quiero cambiar";
/*
.
.
.El código que lo convierte 
.
.
*/
echo $cadenaconvertida;
```

> Resultado: "Esta_la_cadena_que_quiero_cambiar"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tienes muchas alternativas en **PHP**.

> **strtr:**

**strtr** es utilizado para reemplazar caracteres de manera consecutiva, reemplaza todas las apariciones de cada carácter (byte simple). Éste puede mostrar resultados "inesperados" al agregar múltiples caracteres ya que interpreta que cada carácter de forma independiente. **Por ejemplo:**

```
echo strtr("ABCBADEFG", "BA", "12");
// Resultado: "21C12DEFG"
```

- **Estructura:**

---

string **strtr** ( string **$cadena** , string **$from** , string **$to** )

---

string **strtr** ( string **$cadena** , array **$pares_reemplazar** )

---

- **Tiempo de respuesta (promedio):** 40.9357118607 segundos
- **Referencia:** [Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtr.php)

---

> En respuesta:

```
$cadena = "Esta es la cadena que quiero cambiar";

$cadenaConvert = strtr($cadena, " ", "_");

echo $cadenaConvert;
```

---

> **preg_replace:**

**preg_replace** realiza una búsqueda y sustitución de una expresión regular.

- **Estructura:**

mixed **preg_replace** ( mixed **$patrón** , mixed 
**$reemplazo** , mixed **$cadena** [, int **$limite** = -1 [, int **&$contador** ]] )

---

- **Tiempo de respuesta (promedio):** 3.27423620224 seconds
- **Referencia:** [Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php)

---

> En respuesta:

```
$cadena = "Esta es la cadena que quiero cambiar";

$cadenaConvert = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $cadena);

echo $cadenaConvert;
```

---

> **str_replace:** (la mas recomendable y rápida)

**str_replace** reemplaza todas las apariciones del string buscado con el string de reemplazo. Esta función devuelve un string o un array con todas las apariciones de **search** en **subject** reemplazadas con el valor dado de **reemplazo**. **search** y **reemplazo** puede ser un string o un array. En caso de ser array, se realiza un equivalente con el array de menor indice para las sustituciones.

- **Estructura:**

mixed **str_replace** ( mixed **$search** , mixed **$reemplazo** , mixed **$subject** [, int **&$count** ] )

---

- **Tiempo de respuesta (promedio):** 1.49082899094 seconds
- **Referencia:** [Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

---

> En respuesta:

```
$cadena = "Esta es la cadena que quiero cambiar";

$cadenaConvert = str_replace(" ", "_", $cadena);

echo $cadenaConvert;
```

> Resultado para todos:  "Esta_es_la_cadena_que_quiero_cambiar"
>
> **Referencia de tiempos de respuesta:** [Aquí](https://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=175031.0)

Comment: si tan solo explicaran cuales son los parametros de entrada , y le agregaran el enlace de la documentacion  oficial , eso seria una gran respuesta , eso esta bien para el estudiante que copia y pega pero para los que desarrollamos no nos ayuda porque queremos saber como funciona

Comment: No te entiendo, ¿podrias ser un poco mas objetivo por favor?

Comment: @CesarVelasquez actualizada la respuesta. Espero se entienda mejor

Comment: @JackNavaRow actualizado, he actualizado la respuesta. Saludos